# Read in a sentence and print out only words that have the same letter repeated 3 or more times in a row

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I wanted to make a program in which only repeats words that has 3 of the same letters back to back. eg the mooonkey raaan through the mounnntains. the program should only repeat mooonkey, raaan

```
public class Triplets2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("write a sentence");
    String in = input.nextLine();
    
    String [] sentence = in.split(" ");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
        
        char [] word = sentence[i].toCharArray();
        int counter =0;
        
        for (int s = 0; s < word.length; s++) {
            
            char letter = word[s];
            
            for (int x = 0; x<word.length; x++) {
                
                if (letter == word[x]) {
                    counter++;
                }
                    else {
                        counter = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        if (counter >=3) {
            System.out.print(sentence[i] + ",  ");
        }
    }
}
```

the program instead just repeats nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking for consecutive letters you want to start at char `i` and then compare the char at `i` to char at `i+1` and at `i+2`. If they are all equal then we have a match and can continue.

You can simplify the whole function such as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("write a sentence");
  String in = input.nextLine();

  List<String> tripleLetter = new ArrayList<>();
  for (String s : in.split(" ")) {
    char[] word = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length - 2; i++) {
      if ((word[i] == word[i+1]) && (word[i] == word[i+2])) {
        tripleLetter.add(s);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  System.out.println(tripleLetter.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct, the only logical error you made is inside your inner loop you keep resetting your counter variable as soon as you find a letter that is different:

```
if (letter == word[x]) {
    counter++;
} else {
    counter = 0;
}
```

So when you iterate over a word like "raaan" your counter will reset when it reaches the very end of the String, because "n" only exists once.
What this means is that you will only be able to detect words that have 3 consecutive letters at the very end (like "Hooo").

The solution is simple:
Once you found 3 consecutive letters in a word you can just stop iterating and checking the rest of your word. At that point you already know that it fits your criteria:

```
if (letter == word[x]) {
    counter++;
    if(counter >= 3) break; // stop inner loop checking once we found 3 letters
} else {
    counter = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're just looking for a shorter version of doing this then try this.

- first, split the sentence on one or more white space characters (you should be doing that regardless).
- stream the array and filter on a single character, followed by the same two characters via a back reference to the capture group (see [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) for that).
- And print them.

```
String str =
        "Thiiis is aaaa tesssst of finding worrrrds with more than threeeeee letteeeeers";

Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s+"))
        .filter(s -> s.matches(".*(.)\\1\\1.*"))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
Thiiis
aaaa
tesssst
worrrrds
threeeeee
letteeeeers
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to suggest a solution that differs slightly from yours and doesn't use a counter.

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("write a sentence");
String in = input.nextLine();
String[] sentence = in.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    char[] word = sentence[i].toCharArray();
    for (int s = 0; s < word.length - 2; s++) {
        if (word[s] == word[s + 1] && word[s] == word[s + 2]) {
            System.out.print(sentence[i] + ",  ");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Check whether the current letter, in the current word, is the same as the next letter and the same as the letter after the next letter. If the condition holds, then print the current word and proceed to the next word in the sentence.